# I am trying to make to-do list using jquery ui but .ui-icon-close is not working? How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, project

```
    $("#project").on("click", "span.ui-icon-close", function () {
       var index = $(this).closest("li").index();
       var id = $("#main li :eq(" + index + ") a").attr("href");
       $("#main li:eq("+ index + ")").remove();
       $(id).remove();});
    $("<li><a href=' #" + replaceName + " '>" + projectName + "</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'></li>").appendTo("#main");
    <li><a href="#personal">Personal</a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></li>
```

I am using jquery ui cdn link.
this project - [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcglP57mc0A&list=PLf1qCOLSl4H0w5WwyG8oOWqfgl_FXrf43&index=3&ab_channel=CryptersInfotech](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
in this part aprox time - 2.50

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've missed "s" letter in the first row, and put an extra space before the ":eq".

I can't see all of your code, but hope it will help.

```
$("#projects").on("click", "span.ui-icon-close", function () {
    var index = $(this).closest("li").index();
    var id = $("#main li:eq(" + index + ") a").attr("href");
    $("#main li:eq("+ index + ")").remove();
    $(id).remove();
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR RESPONCE, I HAVE UPLORDED IN GITHUB AND PROVIDING YOU MY REPO LINK. IF YOU CAN HELP ME PLEASE MAKE THE NECESSARY CHANGES AND THEN COMMIT CHANGES. https://github.com/Dibya5425/Todo-List